# Can't create an instance of ViewModel when using Hilt with Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel, dagger-hilt

I'm using `Hilt` with `Jetpack Compose`.

```
@HiltViewModel
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val homeRepository: HomeRepository
): ViewModel() {

fun getCarDetails(): Car {
    return homeRepository.getCarDetails()
}
}
```

That's how I inject the repo.

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)

abstract class DataModule {

    @Binds
    @Singleton
    abstract fun bindHomeRepository(
        homeRepository: HomeRepositoryImpl,
    ): HomeRepository
}
```

And that's my composable.

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(viewModel: HomeViewModel = viewModel()) {
    val carData = viewModel.getCarDetails()
    Column(
        Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        TopBar(carData = carData, modifier = Modifier)
        CarImage(carData = carData, modifier = Modifier)
    }
}
```

I've annotated my `Activity` with `@AndroidEntryPoint`. Can't figure out what's the problem. It crashes with a message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.carcontroller.ui.HomeViewModel
```

My library versions for `compose` is `1.2.1` and for `hilt` `2.43.2`. Compose ViewModel version is `2.5.1`.

**EDIT:** I fixed the crash and below answered how. Hope that will help someone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, the developer's page isn't updated yet.

There's a library called hilt navigation compose:

```
implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0"
```

After syncing we need to use `hiltViewModel()` instead of `viewModel()` like this

```
fun HomeScreen(viewModel: HomeViewModel = hiltViewModel())
```

Now it's not crashing. Thank you.